# jQuery Slider - update value

Tags: jquery-ui, animation, slider

I am using the following to update the slider value:

```
$("#slider").slider("option", "value", intervalCounter);
```

It works for single change, however if I use it in an animation it stops the animation

```
intervalCounter = 100;
if (intervalCounter < intervalMax) {
    ......
}
++intervalCounter;
$("#slider").slider("option", "value", intervalCounter);
```

I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) ? Hard to imagine what you try to achieve. The built-in possibility [here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax) doesn't do what you want? You could update the value on each slide.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to put a demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: I guess the problem was in my page, I made a new page with simple test and it worked fine.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find any way to do it, I used jquery ui slider; not as good as Telerik MVC slider; but it did the required job.